# Shouldn't the column start with special characters?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm working with Excel sheet of .xls format and writing data into it. The problem is that whenever the data doesn't start with alphabets it is prompting me different errors.

For example: When my column data started with **=?us-ascii?Q?Google Keywords?=** it threw me an exception:

```
 Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

and when my data is like **-------- Original Message --------Subject:** the error was:

```
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY))
```

This is how I'm writing data:

```
 foreach (AllCasesReplies infoList in allCasesReplies)
  {
      n = 0;
      mWorkSheet.Cells[l + m, ++n] = infoList.id;
      mWorkSheet.Cells[l + m, ++n] = infoList.replies;
      m++;
   }
```

This is how I clean my objects:

```
private static void SaveAndCollecttheGarbage(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp, string path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheet)
{
        excelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
        mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        mWorkBook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        sheet = null;
        mWorkBook = null;
        excelApplication.Quit();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
}
```

So I have tried omitting these data and they are working great.

Are there any rules that the column has to start with specific characters and if so, what are these?

Comment: What does a formula start with in Excel? How do you escape that character? ...

Comment: Which library are you using when writing to excel?

Comment: I didn't get you? I'm not using any formula.If you are asking how I omitted those columns,I didn't add to the "list" from I'm writing to Excel

Comment: How are you writing these into Excel?

Comment: From the Xml, I'm adding the required fields to the list and then looping through the list and writing to the Excel

Comment: Are you cleaning up your excel objects properly?

Answer (score 0):

if you type "?" in excel cell that has general format, the excel automaticall interprete that as a formula.  You need to change the cell format before inserting the text into the cell.

something like:

```
foreach (AllCasesReplies infoList in allCasesReplies)
  {
      n = 0;
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range1 = mWorkSheet.Cells[l + m, ++n] as Range;
      range1.NumberFormat = "@";
      range1.Value2 = infoList.id;

      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range2 = mWorkSheet.Cells[l + m, ++n] as Range;
      range2.NumberFormat = "@";
      range2.Value2 = infoList.replies;

      m++;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, it should've been NumberFormat. I have corrected it above.

Comment: May I know what actually it does?The purpose of this property

Comment: The NumberFormat property set the cell format as you would in excel. For examl if you enter the string "=?us-ascii?Q?Google Keywords?= " in excel with cell formatted to 'General' it throw exactly the same exception Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC. However, if you format the cell to 'Text' then excel will not throw exception.

Comment: It is also the case that when the cell format is "General" that text like "-------- Original Message --------Subject:" starting with '-' will be interpreted as formula. Formula has a limited memory, and that will throw out of memory exception.